# Power BI - setting a default filter value dynamically based on the user logged in

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a specific requirement where a report has 4 visuals. When a user logs in, the data should be filtered to the user's default location(s). The default locations are stored in a table with the columns user and Location. Noting this table can contain multiple records for different locations assigned to the same user.

When a user logs in to the report, the data should be filtered to the default locations, but the user should be able to see all locations. I have not come across a suitable solution, and the recommended approaches result in the table being filtered meaning the user cannot then not select other locations from the slicer.

Is someone able to assist?